# How to check value transition in Django (django-admin)?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I have a status field which has 3 values: pending, activated
and rejected. If I am changing the value of status I want to
have a check that activated cannot be changed to pending. I
do not want to write stored-procs for this. Can I have the
previous value in Django before saving?

Means new and old value.

Comment: +1 - I've been wondering the same thing. In my case there's some heavy duty work that gets done in a save method that is only necessary if a field in a particular subset of model's fields have changed, and I've been looking for a way to check whether or not this is the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def clean_status(self):
    status = self.cleaned_data.get('status')
    if status == 'pending':
        if self.instance and self.instance.status == 'activated':
            raise forms.ValidationError('You cannot change activated to pending')

    return status
```

This method is to be added in a `Form` subclass. Its name is `clean_FIELD_NAME`.

`cleaned_data` contains previous values. New value is stored in `self.instance`.

Alternatively, `validate()` method can be added to a `forms.Field` subclass. [See Django documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: hey Dominic Rodger can u help in 'inline-django'.My question in django

Answer (score 9):

You can do this in an overridden `save` method. The thing to remember is that Django model instances aren't the actual database objects, they just get their values from there on load. So you can easily go back to the database before saving your current object to get the existing values.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.status == 'pending':
         old_instance = MyClass.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
         if old_instance.status == 'activated':
              raise SomeError
     super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

There is currently no good way of returning an error message to the user other than raising an exception. There is a Google Summer of Code project currently under way to enable 'model validation', but this will not be ready for a few months.

If you want to do something similar in the admin, the best way is to define a custom ModelForm with an overridden `clean()` method. However, this time since this is a form you already have access to the old values without hitting the db again. Another benefit is that you can return a form validation error to the user.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

     class Meta:
          model = MyModel

    def clean_status(self):
        status = self.cleaned_data.get('status', '')
        if status == 'pending':
             if self.instance and self.instance.status == 'activated':
                  raise forms.ValidationError(
                      'You cannot change activated to pending'
                  )
         return status

 class MyModelAdmin(forms.ModelAdmin):
     form = MyModelForm
     model = MyModel
```

Comment: that's because you should probably override ModelAdmin.save_model method: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods

Comment: I've added an alternative using the admin above.

Comment: the if condition should be 
if self.instance and self.instance.status == 'activated':
raise forms.ValidiationError

Comment: Gah!!! Been messing about with signals and turning my code into spaghetti for hours now!! This is what I wanted...

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered elsewhere on Stack Overflow, but the correct way is to use something like [this](https://github.com/smn/django-dirtyfields) to track whether fields are dirty. Then you could use a signal to denote that something has changed that's of importance. (i.e. your field)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the save method, wouldn't this be a good place to use signals? Intercept the save before commit, check the current value in the database, and either forward the save on, or reject it?

Now I'm not sure if the signal blocks the save request or if it happens asynch, so feel free to downvote this answer if a signal can not be used to prevent the save happening upon validation.

I'm against overriding inbuilt methods if there is another inbuilt tool that works just as well.

Comment: I think, overwriting save() and delete() can be good practice. 

I have a the classes Photo and Thumbnail. 

The Thumb has a item = models.ForeignKey(Photo). 

photo.delete() is overwritten and will delete all thumbs (for t in self.thumbnail_set.all():t.delete()) before running super(Photo, self).delete() .

If the removing of the thumb would be done in a signal, the maintaining of the code would be harder.

Comment: but __init__ I wolud never overload. I would use signal instead.

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread while searching for an answer to the same question. Why not do something like this? This way you can avoid touching database. And inbuilt `__init__` just a little extended. I think it's much more simple way than using signals.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_fair_field = ....

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__clean_fair_field = self.my_fair_field

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # check if field value changed
        if self.__clean_fair_field != self.my_fair_field
                 # ...do some work...

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```